# how can I prevent networkd from raising interface while still allowing dhcp configuration

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

I am trying to use systemd-networkd to configure my network. I would like to have a dhcp setting but I must keep the interface from being up. The step scenario would be

- Machine boot up
- Network interfaces are down
- Manual raising of net-interface
- Requests to dhcp are made.

I have not beeen able to keep interfaces down and dhcp config. I also tried having no config and managing request using dhclient but having multiple interfaces gives me a weird routing-table(this in itself could be another question in the future).

For a bit more information. I have a regular RJ45 network port and several USB modems that I would like to plugin without automatic-connect.

Comment: IMHO there is no way to keep ethernet-interfaces down and still do DHCP. Is your goal to keep Ethernet down and configure network via the modems when they are plugged in only?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distro you could add
`ONBOOT=no` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/your-interface`
That way the interface stays down after reboot and can be enabled via:
`ifup your-interface`

To enable DHCP you can add
`BOOTPROTO=dhcp` to the same file